# echo -> html = chaos

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I try to output a database Table in PHP within a HTML Table. When I view the output in HTML, It is totally messed up. In my opinion everything is correct. Maybe someone of you see the mistake.

### My PHP file:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display table table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-md-3">Gespeichert am</th>
<th class="col-md-5">Text</th>
<th class="col-md-3">Kategorie</th>
<th class="col-md-1"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".date("H:i - d.m.y",strtotime($row->Zeit) + 60*60)."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='".$row->url."' target='_blank'>".$row->text."</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$row->kategorie."</td>";
echo "<form action='delete.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='".$row->id."'</td>";
echo "<button onClick='submit();' style='border:none; background-color:transparent; padding:0px;' type='submit' value='Delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

### My output in HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display table table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-md-3">Gespeichert am</th>
<th class="col-md-5">Text</th>
<th class="col-md-3">Kategorie</th>
<th class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>15:46 - 26.03.15</td>
<td><a href="http://Www.google.de" target="_blank">Google link</a></td>
<td>Web</td>
<form action="delete.php" method="post"></form>
<td><input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="37" <="" td="">
<button onclick="submit();" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; padding:0px;" type="submit" value="Delete">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If the form is supposed to be inside a cell, then put it inside the cell

Comment: Mistake here: `echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='".$row->id."'</td>";`. Should be `echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='".$row->id."'/></td>";` (closing tag missing).

Comment: @MarkBaker I need a "valid, well formatted HTML" Table in order to use Datatables.

Comment: I've pointed out two issues already that prevent your table from being "valid, well formatted HTML".... try fixing those

Comment: @MarkBaker [check this](https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put `<form>` inside cell of table (inside the `<td>`), or wrap it around entire table.

The problem is that `<tr>` allows only `<th>` and `<td>` nodes inside and that's why your `<form>` is getting messed up.

Also, as someone already mentioned in comments, the following line has errors which result in broken html:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='".$row->id."'</td>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='".$row->id."'></td>";
```